# Promises or deferred for multiple events (using custom event)

Tags: jquery

I have a custom event called `render`. A lot of loosely coupled components of my application are bound to it and they re-render themselves after the event has been fired.

Now I'd like to execute a function after all the renderings are completed (pseudo code):

```
triggerEvent("render");

when(renderingComplete).then(alert("Hurray!"));
```

How can I achieve that? Where do I need to create/return deferreds?

(Another thing which might get tricky: As far as I understand, functions need to return a `deferred`-object, but my `render()`-functions also need to return the HTML code in order for my rendering system to work :-S)

Comment: You can return an object like { content : html, promise : referedObject.promise() }, but what does the refered object say? that the rendering is complete? you wont be able to return both the promise and the result at the same time, please clarify your issue.

Comment: Exactly, the deferred object says that the rendering is complete. This is also why I think that it might get tricky...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to render using an asynchronous function (explaining why you need a deferred object), you could use something like this:

```
function render(args) {
  var def = $.Deferred();

  // call async function to render, example using ajax
  // if you could use ajax then you wouldnt need to create your own deferred 
  $.post(url,data)
    .done(function (data) {
      def.resolve(data);
    })
    .fail(function (e) {
      def.reject(e);
    });

  // Return promise that can be used to capture success or failure of rendering
  return def.promise();
}

render().done(function (data) {
  // data has whatever was passed in resolve(data)
}).fail(function (e) {
  // handle error
});
```

The biggest issue is how you implement the async functions used to render the html. If it can be done with ajax then it becomes a trivial issue as jquery ajax functions return a deferred object (see $.post in example).

However, if the rendering is not async, and what you want is to launch an event after the rendering is done, then it should be doable by adding a new custom event to be fired at the end of your render function with the resulting html as a parameter/attribute, a "afterRender" custom event if you will.